# c++ linked list inside another one

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to make a linked list inside another one, here is my code

```
template<typename T>
class List {
private:
    int length;
    class Node {
    public:
        T data;
        Node* next;
    } *head;

public:
    List();
    ~List();

    void insert(T item);
    void remove(T item);
    void empty();
    T* getAll();
    int count() const;       
};

template<typename T>
void List<T>::insert(T item)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = new Node();
        head->data = item;
        head->next = NULL;
        length = 1;
        return;
    }
    Node* p = new Node();
    p->data = item;
    p->next = head;
    head = p;
    ++length;
}

struct Remainder {
    Date dt;
    List<int> notes;
};


void getDayEvents(Date dt, List<Remainder> l)
{
    Remainder* arr = new Remainder[l.count()];
    arr = l.getAll();
    for (int i = 0; i < l.count(); i++)
    {
        if (arr[i].dt.day == dt.day && arr[i].dt.month == dt.month &&              arr[i].dt.year == dt.year)
        {
            int* nArr = new int[arr[i].notes.count()];
            nArr = arr[i].notes.getAll();
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].notes.count(); j++)
            {
                cout << nArr[j] << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}

int _tmain() {
    Date dt1, dt2;
    dt1.setDate(17, 7, 2015);
    dt2.setDate(5, 11, 2015);

    Remainder r1, r2;
    r1.dt = dt1;
    r1.notes.insert(1);
    r1.notes.insert(2);
    r2.dt = dt2;
    r2.notes.insert(5);

    List<Remainder> l;
    l.insert(r1);
    l.insert(r2);

    getDayEvents(dt1, l);

    //----------------------------------------------------------
    int pause;
    cin >> pause;
    return 0;
}
```

just when insert r1 or r2 in the list, the data inside lists of notes inside each remainder just disappeared or destroyed

I don't know why? Where is the mistake?

Comment: Can you show more of your source; Date is either a class or struct and don't see any implementation, and for you List class, you do not show any of your implementation there either. It is hard to tell where your error could be.

Comment: i added the implementation of insert method of the list and the date class declaration. Do you need any more info ? .. thanks for giving help :)

Comment: I edited your original post to improve formatting for better readability. Only visible to me until it is approved by peer review.

Comment: now better i think :) thanks

Comment: It makes it harder to read without the indentation.

Comment: when i debug the code, i found that the notes data destroyed just when i return form the insert method while inserting the remainder in the list

Comment: For clarification are you writing a single linked list or double linked list?

Comment: i don't understand the question but in general i implemented one class linked list with T type, then i've made one instance as list of Remainder that has also a list of string inside

Comment: A single link list has a forward pointer only as in head -> e1 -> e2 -> e3 -> tail where a double linked list has head < = > e1 < = > e2 < = > e3

Comment: I also do not see your insert() method

Comment: head -> e1 -> e2 -> e3 -> NULL

Comment: Ah ok so a single linked list

Comment: just when finish insertion of the remainder the data inside the notes list inside just disappeared

Comment: i noticed that i just can't do like this
    List<int> x, y;
    x.insert(1);
    x.insert(2);
    y = x;

Comment: may be i should implement what assignment operator should do ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You haven't given us enough code to reproduce the error (e.g. what is `Date`?), which makes our job much harder. Also, you could probably simplify this code a good deal and still have a working example of the error. (This is what ["minimal complete example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) refers to.) Finally, if you develop new functionality in isolation, you'll have fewer problems like this.

Comment: Is there something wrong with `std::list<std::list<SomeType> > >`?

Answer (score 3):

You're passing your objects into the `insert` function by value.
That means copy constructors and destructors are being called.
You did not declare the copy constructor of `List` so it's presumably
being generated by the compiler, and presumably is making a
"shallow" copy of the `List` when the copy constructor
of `Remainder` makes copies of the members of the input `Remainder`.

I think this copies the pointer `head` from one `List` to another
so that now you have
two `List` objects whose `head` pointers point to the same object.
You haven't shown the definition of the `List` destructor,
but depending on what you do in that destructor it could be deleting
a `Node` that the destroyed `List` points to while another `List`
still has a pointer to the same `Node`.

That may sound confusing, and frankly I'm not sure I can count the
invocations of constructors and destructors correctly myself,
so best to just make sure they can never be used unsafely.

A good start might be to define your own copy constructor and
`operator =` for `List` in such a way that the new `List` has
newly-allocated copies of everything that was in the old `List`.
Never let two `head` pointers point to the same object.
After you've inserted one `List` into another, you should be able to
confirm in the debugger that the new copy of the `List`